# How to write linear constraints under some if condition for GA?

Tags: matlab

For linear constraints we write matrix A and b.

I want to write some constraints only when some condition satisfied. Suppose we have two constraints:

```
x(1) + 2*x(2) <= 6; 
x(1) - x(2) + 2*x(3) <= 7;
```

so my A and b are:

```
A = [1 2 0; 1 -1 2] 
b = [6 7]
```

Now I want to check my second constraint only when `x(4) >=0`
How can I write this for [GA](https://mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html) in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick:

```
bigNumber = 1e+9; % may depend on your application
A = [1 2 0 0; 1 -1 2 bigNumber] 
b = [6 7]
```

*Explanation*

If `x(4) < 0`, then the second constraint will always be satisfied, because `x(4) * bigNumber << 0` as long as `bigNumber >> abs(x)`.

As an **alternative**, you can first solve the problem as you stated it above. Then, check if `x(4) >= 0`. If not, calculate the problem without the second constraint (and add `x(4) < 0`).